# PHP Warning: include_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-hosting

When I upload my application on server, I'm getting a bunch of these warnings:
`PHP Warning:  include_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool...`

I know, there are loads of tutorials how to solve this problem on your server, but the server where I have my application, is not mine - it´s public hosting. Therefore I´d like to ask, how can be this problem solved? Do I have to contact my hosting provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an APC bug, try to disable it on `.htaccess` (`php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off`) or increase the `apc.shm_size` parameter in the `apc.ini` file.

Perhaps you have to contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
apc.ttl=0
apc.shm_size=anything you want
//And you can try this to test you is APC operational
function is_file_cached($file) {
$info = apc_cache_info();
foreach ($info['cache_list'] as $cache) {
    if ($cache['filename'] == $file) return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Can help you if you can edit php.ini on you public hosting
Using a TTL of 0 means that APC will flush all the cache when it runs out of memory.
How ever I believe your hosting don't have most up to date php version and error is because
APC bug or php-fpm problem with used php version

Useful would be to know your APC version running with php